# MeteorJS high response time on Heroku

Tags: heroku, meteor, sockjs

I am running a Meteor app on Heroku and the Heroku response time chart is constantly filled with high response time queries hitting 30 seconds limit

[image]

The router logs shows that all the 30 seconds queries are some kind of sockJS xhr call

```
14 Aug 2021 11:37:33.249334 <158>1 2021-08-14T03:37:32.837295+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=POST path="/sockjs/950/pwiv10fk/xhr" host=www.abc.com request_id=edbe326a-cddd-4e5e-9347-0f5c1c49651b fwd="121.6.80.103,162.158.165.53" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=29493ms status=200 bytes=384 protocol=httpHigh Response Time
14 Aug 2021 11:37:33.358335 <158>1 2021-08-14T03:37:32.837093+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=POST path="/sockjs/707/7haw05h4/xhr" host=www.abc.com request_id=20ca52a2-5aa4-43fa-bb61-39462eb0ab86 fwd="121.6.80.103,162.158.167.169" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=29484ms status=200 bytes=384 protocol=httpHigh Response Time
14 Aug 2021 11:38:03.405335 <158>1 2021-08-14T03:38:02.836998+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=POST path="/sockjs/950/pwiv10fk/xhr" host=www.abc.com request_id=f3a51bc3-9319-4b80-91b5-ed76bf179493 fwd="121.6.80.103,162.158.166.136" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=29480ms status=200 bytes=384 protocol=httpHigh Response Time
```

The reality is that there is only a few users on the app, and no unusual activity happening on server. Actually the users did not experience slow down as well, so i suspect, the socket connections mechanisms on Meteor app is polluting the heroku response time charts, I also have to turn off slow response time alerts because they are too many.

These non-stops 30 seconds response times calls creates a problem which I do not really know the true speed of the web app.

What is happening and how to avoid this?

Comment: The example you show seems to be requests from different IPs, so this doesn't seem to be a systematic issue on the server. Do you know what the two IPs in the `fwd` field in the router log signify?

Comment: @ChristianFritz based on a random check on a slow request, the first IP address in the fwd address is the client's browser ip address, the second IP address is the cloudflare's ip address

Comment: hm, interesting. Maybe the issue is introduced by Cloudflare. They might interrupt your websocket connections. Have you tried what happens when you connect to your web application direclty (not through cloudflare)?

Comment: @ChristianFritz very interesting suggestion. I will test on this direction, thanks!

Comment: @ChristianFritz We finally had chance to turn off cloudflare and the timing chart appears a lot normal. Thanks for pointing me to this direction. You can post your comment as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Great. Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was introduced by Cloudflare. They seem to have been interrupting the websocket connections, causing Meteor to fall back to polling, which is not efficient.